# Vertical line only in one part of a table

Tags: tabularx

I need some help on  putting a vertical line in the second part of the table, I don't know how to do it since the `tabularx` I declared does need to have that only in the second part. The code I used is:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|XX|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{title name}}\\
\hline
something: & else \\
something: & else \\
something: & else \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{bla bla blah}\\
\hline
title text: & description 1 \\
title text: & description 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

And the render of the table looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFQI1.png]

I just need a `\vline` between title text and description (it I use `\vline` it works only for the first line but the description text and sometimes the title, are few lines long).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I uploaded the image for you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would just place the respective items in a `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|XX|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{title name}}\\
  \hline
  something: & else \\
  something: & else \\
  something: & else \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{bla bla blah}\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{title text:} & description 1 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{title text:} & description 1 \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx with correct column lines]

For an improved visual layout of tables, I would suggest using the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). It provides different horizontal lines (of varying thickness) that neatly separates the table headers and contents. However, due to this, spacing with vertical lines (down a column) is considered problematic. In fact, the [`booktabs` documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) stipulates two main points to consider when making publication-style tables:

1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
2. Never use double rules.

The reason for the first restriction is because table inherently have some horizontal alignment with their columnar structure. As such, adding a vertical line would emphasize the obvious. Here's a mock-up of your original MWE that shows the table using a standard `booktabs` representation:

[image: booktabs tabularx]

Comment: Thanks, it works. But if the title text is too long (I use title text of 2 lines) it just takes all the space.
I am now using {|X|} and it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: If your `title text:` is much longer than in your MWE, you can put it in a `\parbox{<width>}` where you specify the `<width>`. If this explanation isn't sufficient, please update your original question with an expanded MWE.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a macro for placing vline between arbitrary cells:

```
\def\arrvline{\hfil\kern\arraycolsep\vline\kern-\arraycolsep\hfilneg}
```

Example:

```
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
    a & b \arrvline& c & d\\
    f \arrvline& 1asd & 2 & g \\
    f & 1asd & 2 & g \\
\end{array}
$$
```

Will produce:

[image: pdflatex output]

(Probably won't work correctly for right-justified columns)

Comment: Hi @vftdan I am trying to use this solution but noticing the vertical lines don't match up. Is there some way to align them? Please see this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513687/box-method-area-model-for-polynomial-division-in-latex